# Best way to retrieve users using FOS user bundle 1.3

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, user-profile

I've a UserBundle (extend FOS (**1.3**)).

I ask me what's the best solution to retrieve users with FOS ?

Is better to retrieve users with my personal UserController and using User Manager (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/user_manager.md)

Your help will help me !

I thank you all

Comment: Please reformulate your question, there are a lot of questions, it's too broad, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UserManager you linked to, but the most common use of users with FOSUserBundle, and what I guess your case is, is to use your own User class, given that it extends the FOSUser class. The inheritance between your User class and FosUserBundle's is what makes you handle 'FOS users'.